# use htaccess to deny access to a js file if it is opened directly from the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i am a noob in htaccess so i want some help please !
 i want to deny access to a js file if it is opened ftom the url bar ex ( when i type http://mysite.com/js/jquery.js in the address bar - i get a 403 ) but when the site is rendered by the browser it is downloaded to the browser normally .

for the moment i was trying this

```
   <Files ~ "(.js|.css)">
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>
```

but this prevents the browser to use the css and the js so i want to make a kind of rule to let the browser but not anyone directly from the url . can in this case use the referer or the host or something like this ?

(note : i don't want to prevent the clients from viewing the js code because they could do it anyway but i have my reasons)

Comment: Care to explain your reasons?

Comment: @earino i edited the question and the reason it is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the same as preventing image hotlinking. See http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html.

i.e:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ - [F]
```

Comment: in this way i prevent hotlinking but when i type in the address bar the exact path of the js i get the js and i dont want to get it in this way

Comment: Oh right, the code allowed blank referrers. I've edited it to remove the corresponding line, I think that should work.

Comment: i tried it before you edited it and it doesn't work for me . does it work for you ? maybe i have missconfigured the apache that's why im asking

Comment: i had a missconfig in the apache . thanks it was what i was looking for . now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Set in your index.php a Cookie value, that indicates your js.php file (Store your js Code in a php file und echo it to the browser) if a request was made on your main page. If the cookie is not set, send a 404 otherwise echo the js code.

Comment: this was the plane B but it was the long way. now i solved it thanks to freejosh . thank you too

Answer (score 0):

Reddit post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660862/4766489
Correct answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```